# Create array with key from dict with sorted by dict values

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have an dictionary that I want to iterate trough in a tableview. One way of doing this is to create an array with all the keys and just fetch the key at the given index. But for this array I want the keys to be ordered alphabetically by the values in the dictionary. How do I do this?

```
static let dict = [
            "0P0000KBNA": "Länsförsäkringar Europa Indexnära",
            "0P0000YVZ3": "Länsförsäkringar Global Indexnära",
            "0P0000J1JM": "Länsförsäkringar Sverige Indexnära",
            "0P00013668": "Länsförsäkringar Tillväxtmarknad Indexnära A",
            "0P0000K9E7": "Länsförsäkringar USA Indexnära",
            "0P00005U1J": "Avanza Zero"
        ]

        static let sortedKeys = Array(dict.keys) // How?
```

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, but yes I want to sort the values alphabetically. The index I mean is in my case the section integer which I will use to point to the correct key (sortedKeys[section]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to sort your dictionary by value and map the key

```
let sortedKeys = dict.sorted{$0.value < $1.value}.map{$0.key}   // ["0P00005U1J", "0P0000KBNA", "0P0000YVZ3", "0P0000J1JM", "0P00013668", "0P0000K9E7"]
```

Comment: If you need a localized sort `let sortedKeys = dict.sorted{$0.value.localizedCompare($1.value) == .orderedAscending }.map{$0.key}`  or case insensitive sort as suggested by bashir `let sortedKeys = dict.sorted{$0.value.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.value) == .orderedAscending }.map{$0.key}`

Answer (score 3):

As a minor variation of [@LeoDabus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41982903/4573247), you could access the `keys` property of your dictionary and sort this array according to the corresponding `value` for each key

```
let sortedKeys = dict.keys.sorted { dict[$0]! < dict[$1]! }
print(sortedKeys)
/* ["0P00005U1J", 
    "0P0000KBNA", 
    "0P0000YVZ3",
    "0P0000J1JM",
    "0P00013668", 
    "0P0000K9E7"] */
```

Note also that the forced unwrapping operator `!` is generally to be avoided, but in this particular case, we know that both shorthand arguments `$0` and `$1` in the predicate closure supplied to `sorted(...)` are guaranteed to be valid keys in the dictionary (since your dictionary is immutable: so no asynch risks here).

Comment: Nice approach also and forced unwrapping will never fail. Localized version `let sortedKeys = dict.keys.sorted { dict[$0]!.localizedCompare(dict[$1]!) == .orderedAscending }`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, and likewise! As prompted in the final clause, the unwrapping wont fail in this example, but should be avoided if `dict` was, say, a static mutable property (in which case race conditions might mess things up!).

Comment: Would be interesting to see which one out of yours or Leo's approach would be quicker – as this avoids the `map(_:)`, but does an extra round of hashing and equality checking when using the dictionary's subscript.

Comment: @Hamish my guess would be Leos method; since accessing the computed `keys` property in my approach [will perform the `map(_:)` call anyway](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2028) (although lazily).

Comment: @dfri Just ran a quick benchmark, and it does seem that Leo's is faster – although I don't think the `keys` property is the bottleneck, as lazy mapping in this case should have fairly little overhead (also if you do `dict.sorted { dict[$0.key]! < dict[$1.key]! }` instead, it has little impact on the result), which leads me to think that it's the hashing and equality checking that's the source of the slow down.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the benchmarking! Yes most likely the hashing/equality checking; we may also note that this wont just be performed ~n times, but ~n log(n), I guess, on avarage (some kind of introsort in Swift?).

Comment: @dfri Yes, it does indeed appear to do an introsort ([here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L386) and [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift.gyb#L204) in the source if you're interested), so yes O(nlog(n)) complexity :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make a new array of strings called keysArray.

Second, loop over your array of dictionaries and add all the keys to the newly created array.

Now keysArray should be an array of the keys.

Third, sort sortedKeysArray as follow

```
var sortedArray = sortedKeysArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
```

Now we have an array of the sorted Keys.

After this if you need to have an array of the dictionaries, create a new array called sortedDictArray. Then loop over sortedKeysArray we made previously and get the dictionary by key and add it to sortedDictArray. Viola!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: You missread the question. The OP wants it sorted by value not by keys

Answer (score 0):

## Ordered Dictionary

I've used the open source [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary) created by Lukas Kubanek to solve problems like this.

For the usage of this library you can refer to the [example playground](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary/blob/master/Playgrounds/OrderedDictionary.playground/Contents.swift).